# Resize an operating system's partition?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, disk-utility, partition

I recently partitioned my 250 GB SSD to install [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) using Disk Utility. I dedicated 100 GB to [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) and the rest to macOS. I now want to resize the partitions to change [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) to 30 GB and give macOS the rest. Before I installed [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/), the partition was visible in Disk Utility, but now Disk Utility says that the main drive is only 150 GB and only shows the main partition.

macOS version: Sierra 10.12.6

I don't want to buy any partitioning software.

Output of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            150.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s3
   4:                        EFI                         99.2 GB    disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +150.4 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 8192329B-C977-47CC-A86C-C0025E670A61
                                 Unencrypted
```

Comment: It' still there but you made it an EFI partition (disk0s4/99.2 GB)

Comment: @klanomath Didn't see it there! How do I resize it, though? I've never used the `diskutil` command line tools.

Comment: `diskutil resizeVolume disk0s4 30g` and then `diskutil cs resizeStack 8192329B-C977-47CC-A86C-C0025E670A61 219600m` should work but may render ElementaryOS un-bootable.

Comment: @klanomath "Unable to resize because file system volume format does not support resizing"... Could I format the partition first?